# Window.Resources style "could not be resolved" in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I've defined a style resouce in `MainWindow.xaml` as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PageHeader" TargetType="TextBlock">
        ...
```

I'm then trying to use it for a `TextBlock` element in a user control:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PageHeader}">Welcome!</TextBlock>
```

However, I get the error:

> The resource "PageHeader" could not be resolved.

There are no syntax errors in the style specification that I can see. The resolve error is all I get.

I've also tried setting the `TargetType` to an `x:Type` too to no avail. Any pointers here?

Comment: Different files, right? It's out of scope. Put the Style in App.xaml, or in a resource dictionary XAML file that's explicitly included in App.xaml.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That fixed it, thanks. I'd figured UserControls within the window would inherit the resources. If you put that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in two different files, right? It's out of scope. All user controls inherit from their visual parent is [inherited dependency properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.110).aspx), like text formatting. `DataContext` is inherited, but appears not to be inherited by the same mechanism. Resources are not inherited.

Try putting the `Style` in App.xaml, or in a resource dictionary XAML file that's explicitly included in App.xaml. Everybody gets what's in App.xaml.